# Google DFP Interstitial not being scaled on IOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, interstitial, google-dfp

I've been working for a long time on displaying DFP instertitial ads at launch on an IOS app.

But for now, event though i get the ad and i can display it on the screen, I can't manage to have it scaled according to the screen size nor to have it centered.

The creative always appears on the top left corner and keep the size of the creatives I've set.

The "ad unit" is very simple and only the sizes for mobiles apps are specified.

[ad unit parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W9pE.png)

The "line item" also is simple with only the same sizes specified, the type is "house" and it began "immediatly" and "forever".

The creative is a "creation template" which allow scalling, stretching and match the 320*480 size with a 640*960 PNG picture.

[creative parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZiND.png)

On the code side.

My request is set like this:

```
    NSString * shortUnitId = @"startup";//startup is the code for startup instertitials
    self.startInterstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:[DfpPrefix completeAdUnitCodeForShortCode:shortUnitId]];
    self.startInterstitial.delegate = self;
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    request.testDevices = @[uniqueIdentifier];
    [self.startInterstitial loadRequest:request];
```

And when received the ad is displayed with this bit of code:

```
- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(DFPInterstitial *)ad {
//SLog(@"Received ad successfully %@",ad);
[ad presentFromRootViewController:rootViewController];
//  [startInterstitial]
```

Could anyone help me having my ad scaled to my screen size and centre ?

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm seeing the same issue.